# In Java, any reason to use static final variables for strings used only once?

Tags: java, performance, static, constants

From just an efficiency standpoint, in Java, are there any advantages to using static final variables if the strings will only be used once in the code?

Comment: Not in terms of efficiency, it is mainly an advantage in terms of maintainability of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely no. The Java compiler interns the string constants during compilation so creating the constant manually is not a performance optimization. Moreover G1GC has string deduplication feature as per [JEP 192: String Deduplication in G1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/192).

The `static final` field is usually created to improve the code readability, to give meaning to a specific string value and avoid commenting.

Comment: as well as placing constants in "easy-to-find" place usually on top of class instead of bury it somewhere in code (jungles) :-) ... still I'm not a fun of constants for common characters like `static final String BLANK_SPACE = " ";`